# Алгоритм подсчета посетителей

Tags: алгоритм

есть такая задача.
я получаю от пользователя cначало четное число n, и потом прошу чтобы от ввел n записей такого формата

```
+ time name
```

или

```
- time name
```

нужно получить `int max` = Максимальное количество посетителей, которые одновременно были в здании, и `int time` = суммарное время, в течении которого в здании был хотя бы один посетитель.
Допустим

```
n=8
+ 3 Alex
+ 6 Ivan
- 9 Alex
- 10 Ivan
+ 12 Roman
- 19 Roman
+ 21 Ivan
- 25 Ivan
```

выходные данные `int max = 2`, `int time = 18`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int max, time;
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    if ((2 <= n && n <= 10000) && (n % 2 == 0)) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i == n) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            list.add(s);
            // код проверяющий что введено имя верно, что число входов и выходов равно и т.п.
            i++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        list.get(i).split(" ");
        // вот тут тупняк
    }
}
```

подскажите логику как дальше я с полученными строками должен работать?
разбиваю их методом `split()`, потом допустим создаю счетчик если посетитель вошел , то +1 если вышел то -1 и смотрю какое значение максимальное оказалось.
а вот со временем такая идея - тоже счетчик, начинается с 1 и считается каждый раз когда число посетителей было больше одного. вот с этим не могу придумать как реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, я бы отсортировал по времени (кстати, добавил бы проверку, что конкретный посетитель сначала входит, а потом уже выходит), и после этого завел бы переменную суммарного времени, изначально 0, и прибавлял бы к ней время нахождения хотя бы одного посетителя. У вас же есть счетчик числа посетителей, так?

Так вот, если он увеличился с 0 до 1, из счетчика времени *вычитаю* время входа этого посетителя, на котором счетчик увеличился до 1.

Если счетчик упал до нуля - *прибавляю* время выхода этого посетителя, на котором счетчик уменьшился до 0.